# Having trouble with multiple active states in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

Happy Monday fellow stackOverflowers! I would just like to know if there are any ways to keep active states independent of each other when clicked. I cant seem to figure out how to make them independent of each other. I have the state as a toggle. Each button's active status is false by default. When clicked it will toggle the status to opposite. The problem is when one of the button is clicked and the status is toggled, so do the status of other buttons. Please see below for the code:

```
    import React, {Component} from "react";
import { Button, Progress } from 'reactstrap';
import "../src/Questions.css";


const items = [
    {
        question:"Category",
        buttonList: [
            'Games',
            "Business",
            'Education',
            'Lifestyle',
            "Entertainment",
            "Utility",
            "Social",
            "Other"
        ],
        multiple: false,
        answers: [],

    },
    {
        question:"Platform",
        buttonList: [
            'Android',
            'iOS',
            'Both'
        ],
        multiple: false,
        answers: [],

    },
    {
        question:"Design Type",
        buttonList: [
            'Barebones',
            'Stock',
            'Custom'
        ],
        multiple: false,
        answers: [],

    },
    {
        question:"Development Type",
        buttonList: [
            'Native',
            'Web',
            'Hybrid'
        ],
        multiple: false,
        answers: [],

    },
    {
        question:"Does the app connect to a server",
        buttonList: [
            'Yes',
            'No'

        ],
        multiple: false,
        answers: [],

    },
    {
        question:"Does the app require users to sign in",
        buttonList: [
            'Yes',
            'No'

        ],
        multiple: false,
        answers: [],

    },
    {
        question:"Additional Features",
        buttonList: [
            'Audio',
            'Camera',
            '3rd party API',
            "Dashboard",
            "Social login",
            "Task list",
            "Search",
            "Rating system",
            "Chat",
            "Privacy Settings",
            "Gallery",
            "QR code",
            "Calendar",
            "Social sharing",
            "Activity feed",
            "Push notifications",
            "Ads",
            "Multilangual",
            "Feedback",
            "Data collection",
            "Geo location",
            "Office capabilities",
            "Activity tracking",
            "Augmented reality",
            "Virtual reality",
            "Data export",
            "Maps",
            "Backup"
        ],
        multiple: true,
        answers: [],

    },
    {
        question:"Last Step",
        buttonList: [
            'Games3',
            'Business3',
            'Education3'
        ],
        multiple: false,
        answers: [],

    },
];

function checkElementIsSelected(array, element) {
    if (array.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return(array.find(item => {
        return item === element;
    }));
}

class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        value:0,
        count:0,
        display: items[0]['question'],
        active:false

    }};

 handleClickNext = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     this.setState({
         value:this.state.value +10,
         count: this.state.count + 1,
         display: items[this.state.count]['question'],
         email: ''
     })

     console.log('+++', this.state.count);
 }

handleClickAnswer = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const question = this.state.count;
    if (!items[this.state.count].multiple) {
        items[this.state.count].answers = [e.target.value];
    } else {
        if (!checkElementIsSelected (items[this.state.count].answers, e.target.value)) {
            items[this.state.count].answers.push(e.target.value);
        }
    }
    console.log('--- answers: ', items[this.state.count].answers);

        this.setState({
            active:!this.state.active
        })
        console.log("True or False Active",this.state.active );

}


handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push("/Success");
    console.log('***', items);
}

handleEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    items[items.length - 1].answers = [e.target.value];
    console.log("$$$Emails: '", items[items.length - 1].answers);

}


render() {
    let element;
    let next;

    if (this.state.count === items.length) {
        element = <input type="text" onChange={this.handleEmail}/>
        next = <Button color='primary' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Get my estimate</Button>

    } else {
        element = items[this.state.count].buttonList.map(btn => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Button outline color="primary" value={btn} onClick={this.handleClickAnswer} active={this.state.active}>{btn}</Button>
                </div>
            )
        });

        next = <Button onClick={this.handleClickNext} color="primary" size="lg" value='Next'>Next</Button>;
    }


    return(
        <div>
            <div><Progress value={this.state.count * (100 / items.length)} /></div>
            <div className="howMuchText">How much does it cost to build an app</div>
            <div className="questionTitle">{this.state.display}</div>
            <div className="buttonChoices">
                {
                    element
                }
            </div>

            <div className="nextButton">
                {next}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
 }
}

  export default Questions;
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Code snippet looks incomplete. What is `checkElementIsSelected`?

Comment: Sorry, left some elements out for simplification of viewing. I have added them in. checkElementIsSelected is supposed to prevent duplication of buttons to be pushed in the array

Comment: would u like made a very simple example about what u want to achive  ?

Comment: Hey, yes I added a picture of what I have :) @roll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this `active={this.state.active}`
You manage all the button with only one state.active. U need to make one state per button.
Here and example

```
        state {
            btnA:false,
            btnB:false,
            btnC:false
        }

        changeState = (btn) => {
            if(btn === 'a'){
                this.setState( prevState => {
                    return {
                        btnA:  !prevState.btnA
                    }
                })
            }
            .... same for btnB and btn C
        }
        ...

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.state.changeState('a')} >{this.state.btnA?'Btn A is active':'Btn A is not active'}<button>
                <button onClick={this.state.changeState('b')} >{this.state.btnB?'Btn B is active':'Btn B is not active'}<button>
                <button onClick={this.state.changeState('c')} >{this.state.btnB?'Btn C is active':'Btn C is not active'}<button>
            </div>
        )
```

this is just an example about how to manage buttons status with just one state now adapt this example to your code

Answer (score 1):

You've got only one boolean value as a flag for active in `this.state.active`.

Change `this.state.active` to an object with keys corresponding to btn names and store there a boolean flag for each button.